# Remove words if all of them are in a stop words list

Tags: c#, linq, stop-words

I have an array of word(s), it can contain one word or more. In case of one word, it's easy to remove it, but when choose to remove multiple words if they are all in the stop words list is difficult for me to figure it out. I prefer solving it with LINQ.

Imagin, I have this array of strings

```
then use 
then he
the image
and the
should be in
should be written
```

I want to get only

```
then use 
the image
should be written
```

So, the lines that **all it words** are in the stop words should be removed, while keep the lines that has mixed words.

My stop words array
 `string[] stopWords = {"a", "an", "x", "y", "z", "this", "the", "me", "you", "our", "we", "I", "them", "then", "ours", "more", "will", "he", "she", "should", "be", "at", "on", "in", "has", "have", "and"};`

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be to do the following:

```
string[] stopWords = { "a", "an", "x", "y", "z", "this", "the", "me", "you", "our", "we", "I", "them", "ours", "more", "will", "he", "she", "should", "be", "at", "on", "in", "has", "have", "and" };

string input = """"
            then use 
            then he
            the image
            and the
            should be in
            should be written
            """";

var array = input.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var filteredArray = array.Where(x => x.Split(' ').Any(y => !stopWords.Contains(y))).ToList();
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filteredArray);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

First 2 lines are just to setup the data.

The third line converts the string into a array of lines by splitting on newline character. (`Environment.NewLine` ensures that the code works properly on linux as well.)

Fourth line processes each line by splitting the line on space (which gets us individual words) and then checks if there's any word that doesn't exist in `stopWords` list. If any of the words doesn't exist then the `Where` condition is satisfied and the whole line is returned in `filteredArray`.

Fifth line simply concatenates all individual lines to form the final `result` string.

The result should look something like below:

```
then use
then he
the image
should be written
```

Note that in your `stopWords` list, you have the word `them` but not `then`. So the second result line should not be removed.

Comment: Yes, you are right about them/then. I've added then in stop words array.

Comment: Nice description. +1

Answer (score 2):

use Intersect method as follows:

```
    foreach (string word in WordsList)
    {
        List<string> splitData = word.Split(new string[] { " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        bool allOfWordsIsInStopWords = splitData.Intersect(stopWords).Count() == splitData.Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this initial problem description:

> I have an array of word(s), it can contain one word or more. In case of one word, it's easy to remove it, but **when choose to remove multiple words if they are ALL in the stop words list is difficult for me to figure it out**. I prefer solving it with LINQ.

The following code resolves the sentences in bold.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string[] stopWords = { "a", "an", "x", "y", "z", "this", "the", "me", "you", "our", "we", "I", "them", "ours", "more", "will", "he", "she", "should", "be", "at", "on", "in", "has", "have", "and" };

string[] inputStrings = { "then use", "then he", "the image", "and the", "should be in", "should be written" };

var wordSeparatorPattern = new Regex(@"\s+");

var outputStrings = inputStrings.Where((words) => 
{
    return wordSeparatorPattern.Split(words).Any((word) =>
    {
        return !stopWords.Contains(word);
    });
});


foreach (var item in outputStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```